# How to get location of multiple devices?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, mobile

I am making an app that shows certain content to various devices. Basically I have the web app where I set what content to be shown and I used Xamarin to set a mirror of my content to all the devices I have.

Thing is, these devices will be given to drivers, and I need to see the location of those drivers. Is there a way for me to get the location of those devices from the web app? Not from the xamarin apps on the devices, the web app...

Comment: Not familiar with web app but I think you can send the IP address of the device with other info you got, then process the IP address in the web app to determine the country. I'm sure there is another way, but this is what just came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The basic architecture would have three components:

1. A central database to store location data.
2. In the Xamarin app, you will need to collect the location data and upload it to your database via a web service. [Here is a Xamarin demo for location tracking](http://web.archive.org/web/20171031203837/https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BackgroundLocationDemo/).
3. Your web app will call a second web service on a schedule (every ten seconds, or whatever seems appropriate) to retrieve the location data for all drivers and plot it on whatever map you're using.

Unfortunately, there are many more details to unpack than can be contained in this answer. Firstly, a lot will depend on your technology choices for the central database and the web app.

You will also need to think about a few things regarding the tracking in your app. For example, battery impact of continuous tracking will be important. Also, you don't want to (or shouldn't) track your drivers at all times, but only when they are working. And so on.

I hope this can get you started.